# Z-Score and Bootstrap Distribution

Tags: bootstrap, standard-error, z-score

Suppose one wants to know whether the mean income of workers in country A is 20,000 per month.  Suppose from collected sample, one gets 21,000 as the mean income in one's sample.  I remember in stats 101 I calculated Z-score by (21,000 - 20,000) / s.e. of income in the sample.

However, after I read some materials regarding bootstrap, it is stated that one uses the s.e. of the mean from bootstrap distribution rather than mean of income from the sample.  In short, one simulates samples many times, collects the value of means, and compute the s.e. of mean.

I find that these two approaches yield totally different s.e.  Of course, s.e. from the sample is much bigger since s.e. of the mean is concentrated only around the mean.

My question is, which way is more appropriate to calculate s.e. to use in Z-score?  The stats 101's way of bootstrap distribution way?

Comment: If you find a "totally different" SE then you're doing something wrong, because the bootstrap SE of the mean equals the usual SE.  If, as is usual, you are computing the bootstrap *via* simulation, then your SE will differ from the correct SE a tiny bit due to random fluctuations, but that's all.

Comment: @whuber You are right.  I got mixed up. The SE of mean from bootstrap must be closed.  I think the "totally different" value was the standard deviation $\sigma$.  But the SE of mean used to calculate Z-score is $\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}$.  Thanks a lot for pointing this out!!

Comment: Since you found your error, maybe now you can answer your own question?